# ActiveMQ Artemis is not persistent

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis for data delivery, but the data in the queue is not persistent.

When I bring down the server using artemis.cmd stop and restart using artemis.cmd run, the message count in the queue becomes 0.

Broker.xml :

```
<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
<max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
```

Comment: How are you sending your messages?  You need to provide more context this question is insufficient to describe what you are doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a handful of broker and client details that need to be accounted for to ensure messages are persisted to disk.

1. Ensure persistence is enabled on the broker using `<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>`. You've already done this so you're in good shape there.
2. Ensure the `<queue>` you're working with is "durable." This is `true` by default so it doesn't need to be explicitly set on the queue, but if you wanted to set it you would do so with `<durable>true</durable>`.
3. Ensure your client sends the message as persistent. Different protocols and APIs have different defaults so it really depends on what you're using as to how you configure the persistence of the message itself.

To be clear, the `<max-disk-usage>` parameter doesn't control message persistence. It controls the amount of disk the broker will consume before it starts blocking message production.